# How to save file with pickle and return it?

Tags: python, pickle

I have list which is saving in file while while returning I need to 
 (https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval ) do ast.literal_eval  method to getting as element

my list is having combination `lst = FirstName, empid,age,salary,filename`

example my list which is saved in file is `['Joe',101,31,99292,'/home/Joe/Joe.txt']`, If I need to pass this to return I need to use `ast.literal_eval`

How to save with the list in to file with help of pickle and how to return it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a way to save pickle into a file, and then load it again:

Save:

```
s = ['Joe',101,31,99292,'/home/Joe/Joe.txt']

with open("my_file.pcl", "wb") as f:
    p = pickle.dumps(s)
    f.write(p)
```

Load:

```
with open("my_file.pcl", "rb") as f:
    p = f.read()
    s = pickle.loads(p)
    print(s)
```

Result:

```
['Joe', 101, 31, 99292, '/home/Joe/Joe.txt']
```